# How to change value of specified div which occur several times (Tampermonkey)

Tags: javascript, attributes

I have no idea how to change value of specified inpu as I don't know the function which can change some element by its name attribute.

Example code:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="name">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="address">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" name="price">
</div>
```

Now, how can I change input value which has name "address" ?

If this could have "id" attribute then I would use this function

```
document.getElementById("address").value = "162114";
```

but the problem is that source code doesn't use id attribute

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByName('address')[0].value
```

assuming you only have 1 input with name="address"